# Include custom angularjs page in another angularjs pages as user control

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating application using AngularJS and I am beginner at it. I have created one common page for searching with its separate controller and its working fine, but now I want to include this page in my other pages as user control.

My Searching page is like

```
<div class="input-group ex col-md-3" ng-app="searchApp" ng-controller="MainSearchController">
.......
.......//My code here
</div>
```

My controller for Search is:

```
var sApp=angular.module("searchApp",[]); 
  sApp.controller("MainSearchController", function($scope){
    $scope.Merchants={};    
    var DEMerchantInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("DEMerchantInfo"));    
        if(DEMerchantInfo == null || DEMerchantInfo == undefined){
            DEMerchantInfo = new Array;
        }
    $scope.Merchants=DEMerchantInfo;

    $scope.Search=function(){

    var DEMerchantInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("DEMerchantInfo"));    
        if(DEMerchantInfo == null || DEMerchantInfo == undefined){
            DEMerchantInfo = new Array;
        }
            $scope.Merchants=DEMerchantInfo;
    }   
});
```

I am using search page in my other pages like:

```
 <body class="sidebar-mini" ng-app="MerchantApp">
  <div class="search-panels col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-10">
    <div ng-include src=" 'search.html' "></div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

but it is not working for me. its giving error.

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?    p0=MainSearchController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined O/<@file:///.....
```

So can any one please suggest how I can achieve this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how search page template should look like:

```
<div class="input-group ex col-md-3" ng-controller="MainSearchController">
    <!-- My code here -->
</div>
```

Note, that I removed `ng-app="searchApp"` from partial. In your app you will need to add `ng-app="searchApp"` to some parent container, like `body` or `html`.

Then you will need to configure `MerchantApp` like this:

```
angular.module('MerchantApp', [
  // some other module dependencies
  'searchApp'
])
```